# R - data.frames are set to data.table class outside local environment

Tags: r, data.table

Data.table package sets my `data.frame` to `data.table` in global environment in situations when I do not expect it to do so. How can I prevent it?

Example 1: `Data.frame` is passed as an argument into a function. That `data.frame` is then `data.table` in global environment.

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = 1:5, v2 = 6:10)

# some function which uses data.table
foo <- function(df){
  setDT(df)
  df[,v3 := v1 + v2]
  return("hello")
}

foo(df1)

[1] "hello"

str(df1)

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
$ v1: int  1 2 3 4 5
$ v2: int  6 7 8 9 10
```

Example 2: `Data.frame` is passed as an argument into a function. Inside the function the `data.frame` is copied into other variable and this copy is treated as `data.table`. Original `data.frame` is then again `data.table` in global environment.

```
df2 <- data.frame(v1 = 1:5, v2 = 6:10)

# some function which uses data.table
bar <- function(df){
  df_temp <- df          # store value in different variable
  setDT(df_temp)
  df_temp[,v3 := v1 + v2]
  return("hello")
}

bar(df2)

[1] "hello"

str(df2)

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
$ v1: int  1 2 3 4 5
$ v2: int  6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: To copy an object, use `dt = copy(df)`. By the way, there is a `setDF` function that should reverse what happens in example #1, but I think it fails if both are inside a function. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1628

Comment: Couldn't you also use `as.data.table()` in the function?  ... but that makes copies I think.

Comment: *Inside the function the data.frame is copied into other variable* - why you think it is copied? It isn't, if it was copied then a lot of code would be inefficient... `<-` operator isn't equal to *copy*.

Comment: I though that passing a variable as an argument into a function makes a completely "separated object" in the function's environment. It is a concept I am not that familiar with (I am not really a programmer).